# Adding Border to form in Struts2

Tags: struts2

I am Working on Struts2. I have created one login form but not getting how to add border to that form .so how to add Border to form in Struts 2 ??

Thanks in Advance

Comment: That is a simple css work not anything struts2 will do for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to go about it.

Depending on what you actually want, it may be enough to override the default Struts stylesheet:

```
.wwFormTable {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

If you want to put something explicitly on the form itself you'd need to define something on forms in general:

```
form {
    border: ...;
}
```

This will hit *all* forms, if you want it for a specific one, use its id:

```
#theFormId {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the `CSS` class and assign it via `cssClass` attribute.

```
.FormBorder
{
 border:1px solid black;
}
```